# cast float into Minutes and Seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The variable Duration is a float.
How can I convert this into a useable and summable time format?

Please see the example data below with Time_Duration being the wanted outcome:

```
SELECT  '00:00:21.0000000' AS Duration ,  '00:21' AS Time_Duration  UNION
SELECT  '00:01:15.0000000' AS Duration,   '01:15' AS Time_Duration  UNION
SELECT  '00:01:43.0000000' AS Duration,   '01:43' AS Time_Duration  UNION
SELECT  '00:05:50.0000000' AS Duration ,  '05:50' AS Time_Duration
```

I tried to convert the float into a decimal first as in:

```
  select 
     ,FORMAT(FLOOR([Duration])*100 + ([Duration]-FLOOR([Duration]))*60,'00:00') as Time_Duration
     FROM [dbo].[mobile]
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Operand type clash: time is incompatible with float

How can I make 'Duration' useable?

Comment: `'00:00:21.0000000'` is a string, not a float. That string cannot be converted to float, doing so will cause an execution error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go for simple format function as given below.

**Note**: We need to escape `:` with `\`.[See MSDN reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#ExampleD)

```sql
declare @table table(duration varchar(20), timeduration time)
insert into @table
SELECT  '00:00:21.0000000' AS Duration ,  '00:21' AS Time_Duration  UNION
SELECT  '00:01:15.0000000' AS Duration,   '01:15' AS Time_Duration  UNION
SELECT  '00:01:43.0000000' AS Duration,   '01:43' AS Time_Duration  UNION
SELECT  '00:05:50.0000000' AS Duration ,  '05:50' AS Time_Duration

select format(cast(duration as time),N'mm\:ss') as time_duration from @table
```

| time_duration |
| --- |
| 00:21 |
| 01:15 |
| 01:43 |
| 05:50 |